# Jquery show and slideout animation doesn't fully work

Tags: jquery

I am totally confused - When I removed pretty much everything and put the offending code in JSFiddle, it works fine - http://jsfiddle.net/FusGB/

However, in the site, almost the same identical code does not work: http://ezpcinternal.com/sports/index.html (Menu to the left)

What is happening is the first item is doing the effect, then the rest just appear suddenly.

I have been racking my brains over this for the past few hours with no luck - based on the fact that it works in JSfiddle completely confuses me.

It works in IE (tested 8 and 9) - but after the slide up, it reappears for a very short time then disappears (annoying) - and it doesn't work in both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: its working fine for me in my firefox , its the left nav right , whenever i click any item it expands and click again it collapse, its doing the toggle correctly.

Comment: @gov / anyone - Any recommendations for a good movie capturing tool I can use? The best I can explain is - for me in Firefox and Chrome, the slideup works fine but the slide down just does the first item then the rest appears instantly.

Comment: do you mean the smooth effect is not there?

Comment: @wil , do one thing try to do the same sample in a separate brand new page and try the code in the firefox and chrome and check if it is working.The same code you have in jsFiddle. If that is working that means there is some problem in html around it , if that is not working on your browsers , then your browser might got corrupted or some cache problems.

Comment: @Gov - Well done, it is something in the CSS causing it, when I remove the CSS line, it works fine... Not sure what (but it isn't that big) - I think this is going to be a long night!

Comment: @Gov - Traced it down to the specific CSS item - I am going to have to think of something else there. If you want to write that comment up as an answer, I will accept.... CSS was the one thing I didn't test on JSFidle, at the same time, I really did not think it would have any effect on the end result. I was really wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wil , do one thing try to do the same sample in a separate brand new page and try the code in the firefox and chrome and check if it is working.The same code you have in jsFiddle. If that is working that means there is some problem in html around it , if that is not working on your browsers , then your browser might got corrupted or some cache problems. –